# How to limit redirects in the Android native App Ads?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, ads, google-dfp

I have an Android App it's very popular and I make money by showing banner Ads on my App. The problem I am facing is there is no way for me to block Ads that have unlimited redirects. I am being hammered with fraudulent Ads and they download tons of data in my App and my users keep complaining about how much data my App is consuming. So coming to specifics does GMA SDK provides any capability of stopping these redirects or is there any other solution/library someone knows that can help resolve this issue.

I take a reactive approach working with Charles proxy identifying the individual Ads that are responsible for unlimited redirects and then reporting to google or third-party Ad servers.

Expected: Able to restrict the number of the redirects a banner Ad can do in my Android App.

Actual: Unlimited redirects in some of the banner Ads

Answer (score 0):

Usually the different advertisers which are supplying ads to AdMob are setting some redirect urls in order to be able to track some of the data. I do not think there is a way in which you can restrict the redirects since you have no control over the data which is loaded in your ad views. I think the only approach you can take is to set extras to your ad request - e.g. the Native ads for AdMob you can pass a bundle in which you can state whether you want the ad to be personalized or not. I think in this case if you opt for the option of non personalized it should limit the amount of data which is collected through those redirects. Example is below:

```
val adExtras = Bundle()

//"npa" stands for Non-personalized ad
adExtras.putString("npa", "1") //you can put "0" respectively if you want personalized 
adView.loadAd(AdRequestBuilder()
             .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter::class.java, adExtras)
             .build())
```

For the fraudulent ads my question is are you using any other ad networks to mediate to when AdMob is unable to fill a specific ad request? From personal experience I have noticed that some of the smaller ad networks tend to gather data which is not very privacy-aware, so this can lead to some of your users feeling that you are doing something shady. However, I do not think there is anything else which you can do.